# how can insert scema object in mongoose expresss

Tags: express, object, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
this my model app
```

import mongoose, { mongo, Schema } from "mongoose";

const app = mongoose.Schema({
'name':{
type: String
},
'parent':{
type: String
},
'order':{
type:Number
},
'path':{
type: String,
},
'accesses': [
{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "Accesses"
}
]
},
{ timestamps: true },);
export default mongoose.model('Apps',app);

this my model accesses

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from "mongoose";

const accesses = mongoose.Schema({
    'name':{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    'app':[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Apps"
    }]
    },
    { timestamps: true },);
export default mongoose.model('Accesses',accesses);
```

this my controller

```
export const saveApp = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const app = new App(req.body);
        const accesses = app.accesses;
        let newAccs = [];
        for (const acc of accesses)
        {
            const newAcc = await Accesses.findById(acc._id)
            newAccs.push(newAcc);
        }
        app.accesses = newAccs;
        const result = await app.save()
        res.status(201).json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
    }
 }
```

this my client.rest

```
POST http://localhost:3000/app
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Ads Management testing",
    "parent": "null",
    "order": 1,
    "path": "ads-management/",
    "accesses": "63689567eee823ff6f39e969"
}
```

this my result

```
{
  "name": "Ads Management testing",
  "parent": "null",
  "order": 1,
  "path": "ads-management/",
  "accesses": [
    {
      "app": [],
      "_id": "63689567eee823ff6f39e969",
      "name": "rejected",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-07T05:19:35.590Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-07T05:19:35.590Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "_id": "636a09d82ea451f510a56534",
  "createdAt": "2022-11-08T07:48:40.035Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-11-08T07:48:40.035Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

my expecting data nested like this [image]
why in my mongose accesses just put an id not all of object